# How can I smoothly move layers from one position to another when the mouse leaves and enter the window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, parallax

I am refining a parallax effect trying to create a smooth transition between two positions using where the mouse leaves and enters the window.  If you notice the JSFiddle has a 'pop' that I want to replace with the transition. How can I do that?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#layer-one').mousemove(function(e) {
    parallax(e, this, 1);
    parallax(e, document.getElementById('layer-two'), 2);
    parallax(e, document.getElementById('layer-three'), 3);
  });
});

function parallax(e, target, layer) {
  var layer_coeff = 10 / layer;
  var x = ($(window).width() - target.offsetWidth) / 2 - (e.pageX - ($(window).width() / 2)) / layer_coeff;
  var y = ($(window).height() - target.offsetHeight) / 2 - (e.pageY - ($(window).height() / 2)) / layer_coeff;
  $(target).offset({
    top: y,
    left: x
  });
};
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didacus/g4d8cj3k/7/)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you can use GSAP libraries to make that offset effect smoother, this is just a fast example, give it a try:

```js
var initPos = $('#layer-one').position();

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#layer-one').mousemove(function(e) {
    parallax(e, this, 1);
    parallax(e, document.getElementById('layer-two'), 2);
    parallax(e, document.getElementById('layer-three'), 3);
  });
});

function parallax(e, target, layer) {
  var layer_coeff = 10 / layer;
  var x = ($(window).width() - target.offsetWidth) / 2 - (e.pageX - ($(window).width() / 2)) / layer_coeff;
  var y = ($(window).height() - target.offsetHeight) / 2 - (e.pageY - ($(window).height() / 2)) / layer_coeff;
  
  /*$(target).offset({
    top: y,
    left: x
  });*/
  TweenLite.to($(target), 2, {x:x, y:y});
};

document.onmouseleave = function() {
  $("#layer-one").animate({
    opacity: 0.4,
    left: 10,
  }, 'fast');
};
```

```css
.layer {
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
}

#base-layer {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#layer-one {
  background: red;
}

#layer-two {
  background: green;
}

#layer-three {
  background: blue;
}

.slider {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 200px;
}

.slider img {
  width: 80%;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/TweenLite.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/easing/EasePack.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/plugins/CSSPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="base-layer">
  <div id="layer-one" class="layer">
    Content
    <div id="layer-two" class="layer">
      Content
      <div id="layer-three" class="layer">
        Content
        <section class="slider">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/fVWomWz.png">
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for the example. Unfortunately, its not what I am trying to achieve (my bad as I put the wrong JSFiddle there, now I corrected). I am trying to achieve the following 1) Mouse goes out of the window - 2) Parallax layers stays in place based on the last mouse position - 3) Mouse enter the on window from a different place - 4) Parallax layers adjust to that new mouse position. Is this clearer explanation? Right now on my example, if I take the mouse out of the window and return it, the parallax layers jump from one position to another. I wanna a smooth transition.